# Ruby: why isn't my member set in initialize?

Tags: ruby, liquid, jekyll-extensions

I have trouble understanding why my below code fails partially. I try to create Liquid tag for Jekyll. While the the class member "text" is set, the member "xyz" is not set at all. But why?

```
module MyModule
  class MyTag < Liquid::Tag
    def initialize(tag_name, text, tokens)
      super
      @text = text
      @xyz = "HELLO"
    end

    def render(context)
      "Output  #{@text} #{@xyz}"
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('my_tag', MyModule::MyTag)
```

With calling the following

```
{% my_tag de 1234 %}
```

The output of the above is:

```
Output de 1234
```

I expected there would be "HELLO" as well, like:

```
Output de 1234 HELLO
```

What do I miss?

The original code from [the Liquid class is here](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/blob/master/lib/liquid/tag.rb).

Comment: Judging from the code, I'd expect "Output de HELLO", not "Output de 1234 HELLO".

Comment: @SergioTulentsev No, it's exactly like I wrote above. The argument is taken as a full string. You have to split the arguments on your own with Liquid (people say).

Comment: Whats happen if you change `"Output  #{@text} #{@xyz}"` to `"Output  #{@text} '#{@xyz}'"`?

Comment: @TimoSchilling It outputs `Output de 1234 ''`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to work fine with Ruby 2.1.5 and liquid-3.0.6 :

```
require 'liquid'
module MyModule
  class MyTag < Liquid::Tag
    def initialize(tag_name, text, tokens)
      super
      @text = text
      @xyz = "HELLO"
    end

    def render(context)
      "Output  #{@text} #{@xyz}"
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('my_tag', MyModule::MyTag)

@template = Liquid::Template.parse("{% my_tag de 1234 %}")
puts @template.render
#=> "Output  de 1234  HELLO"
```

Comment: I can confirm I have the same output running it from the CLI. It's still broken when using it combined with Jekyll.